# Program for bookmarking long videos on my local hard drive?

Tags: video, bookmarks, media-player

I'd like to be able to open a video, watch it a bit, and then store a bookmark, continue watching maybe bookmark it again, close the video, come back a day or two later, and pick up where I left off watching, and find my other two bookmarks....is there a media player or equivalent plugin for a media player capable of such functionality?

Wouldn't hurt if it had the ability to add annotations as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm sure there are many players with this sort of functionality, here are two:

1. [VLC](http://www.videolan.org):

   [Editing bookmarks](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Basic_Use/Playback):
   [image: 1]
2. [KMPlayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/forums/showthread.php?t=32923):

   During playback:
   [image: 2]

   When no file is open:
   [image: 3]

   Editing bookmarks:
   [image: 4]

Both are fully self-contained players that don't require any external codecs/codec packs installed, although KMPlayer can be configured to utilise external codecs if required.