# How to select 1 hour video clip from multiple folders using VLC

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-editing, media-player, video-playback

I have different collection of video training and I would like to select 1 hour or 30 min video, which can have multiple clips, based on the duration, it may not be exactly 30 min. Is it possible to make such a selection ? The playlist doesn't shows the entire playback time of a playlist. Or is there any other video player which can also save the progress of playback and when I relaunch the app again, the progress is saved and playback starts from the location where I left off.

Comment: See if the second player suggested [here](http://superuser.com/a/497472/138343) helps.